# Eclipse there is only one version at compile with

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors, wear-os

I developed a project and I wanted to add a Plain Text to it. But then I learned that W version do not suppor EditText. So I decided to create a new project. But at compile with option, there is just one choice. And that is the W version. What can I do?

Comment: Make sure you download the respective Android SDK using the Android SDK Manager. It sounds like you've only downloaded Android 4.4W.

Comment: I installed all the 85 packages. Including other versions. It's still the same

Comment: So, do you want to develop for Android Wear or plain Android?

Comment: I don't want to develop for Android Wear. I've solved my problem by installing the 32 bit version. I'm using 64 bit system but 32 bit program solved my issue. Ridicilous